# How to regulate or control an intergalactic highway?

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, military-defense

**Background:**
This universe is set 500 to 700 years in the future. Humans have been able to expand across the galaxy using a series of “star gates”, basically 5 mile wide rings that warp space to shorten journeys by a factor of 10. The humans are able to use these gates along with nuclear engines to travel very quickly to other worlds.

A segment of humanity believes the star gates were put in place by a godlike alien society that they worship. This segment attempts to stop star gate travel and to preserve the gates as methods of transcendence. They want to join their gods who have reached the singularity. They would prefer to keep the gate intact but will settle for an irreversible change in the destination.

For now they are destroying trade ships and navy guards. The Federation is guarding the gates with the navy. Each of the 200 or so discovered gates has one or two cruisers nearby.

The cruisers are a kilometer long cylinder with habitat rings rotating around it. They are armed with large railguns and smaller automated missile turrets and Gatling guns. Nuclear weapons are perfectly acceptable.

The alien worshipers have smaller vessels with nukes and small railguns. They massively out number the navy but their ships are not very effective.

Also the humans have no shield system and cannot just block the gates with a structure due to size and trade limits.

**Question Set:**

- Is there any way the navy can prevent the worshipers from attacking the gates and shutting the trade routes down; and
- Is there any way for the worshipers to succeed in their attacks.

Comment: Would an answer be to simply block the entrance/exit of the gates by some structure? Like an repellent electromagnetic shield?

Comment: Yes but a 5 mile ring is very hard to block using any kind of structure.he government wouldn’t be able to built it. Also these gates need to be used by thousands of ships everyday and trade cannot be disrupted. Thanks

Comment: I would also ask if the "cruisers" can be converted to carry small one man fighters that can match the cult in their trench run tactics.   It would be a matter of a Cesna going toe to toe with an F-22 plus justified space dog-fights.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I like it. Would you do small fighters or heavier frigates  that transverse the gate?

Comment: An electromagnetic shield does not necessarily have to be a physical structure. It would cost a lot of energy to maintain and there needs to be some kind of protocoll to let wanted entities trough. Does the solution need to be "physically possible"?

Comment: Real life Naval Air Craft carries have a protection screen of 25  nautical miles (28.7 Miles)  from the actual carrier and anything at 10 nautical miles out (11.5 miles) is going to have the carrier personel bring out the brown pants.

Comment: Yes I would like it to be possible.

Comment: Are they trying to destroy the gates or just the ships entering them?

Comment: They want to use the gates to join their gods in the next dimension.

Comment: The navy seems to find itself equipped with the wrong platforms for this fight: Too much ship and too many targets. Time to shift the ship-building budget to small gate-guarding ships for a few years until the crisis subsides...or pull a previous generation of smaller ships out of mothballs and start bringing their capabilities up to date..

Comment: Welcome to the site, 11Bravo. Please note that you can notify a single user per comment via the '@<username>' syntax. Enjoy your time here!

Comment: I'll note that shortening travel times by a factor of 10 won't get you to "very quick" travel between worlds - it'll still take many years to travel between most stars at that rate. Traveling across the Milky Way would take 50k years *at the speed of light*, so shortening that to 5k years might not accomplish much.

Comment: The real answer here is in strategy, not tactics. Identify worshiper's bases and destroy them. This is the best way to stop piracy and the only way to win a war.

Comment: Are the gates always on/open? And do they have some sort of ATC setup to regulate who goes through when or is it more like an uncontrolled airfield with first come first served? I'd also agree with user535733 and Alexander, the best defense of these gates would be offensive tactics, either by intel groups and small unit raids, or by finding bases and smashing them with the freed up cruisers after replacement with the smaller, more agile (and hopefully numerous) corvettes/frigates/destroyers or whatever.

Comment: That gates are always open you can fly through them whenever you want as long as you file a flight plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as I discussed in my comments, your issue is like many sci-fi matters:  Scale.  where you're really unique is that you underestimated the distances, not over estimated.   As stated, U.S. Aircraft carriers never go out on their own (nor should any capital ship) and have a protective screen of their own jets, cruisers, destroyers, and submarines to keep the carrier safe (in naval combat, Carriers are terrible at close range and most of their offensive capability is in the planes.   The only arms on the ship are defensive and last resort only... shit got real if a carrier fires it's guns... though a space carrier could also double as a battleship, given the required changes.  Also note, even in battleship theory, the battleship's guns were largely offensive and used to hit distant targets.  It wasn't optimized for close range combat so the screen was developed to protect it too.).

As stated, the Carrier has three rings around it:  120 nautical miles, 25 nautical miles, and 10 nautical miles.   The screen hopes to be tracking and monitoring anything entering the furthest ring by air or sea... and shooting down anything hostile entering the second screen if it hasn't been dealt with sooner.   Anything entering the third screen is a drop everything cause shit's going down panic to stop and will probably cost some officers in the Carrier group (i.e. the carrier and all her escorts) their jobs for so throughly droping the ball.

So a kilometer long "cruiser" with topline 500 to 700 year more advanced guns will definately have no problem keeping a 5 mile wide patch of space clear of anything it doesn't want in that patch of space.

Comment: It’s more than 5 miles. Approach vectors and the nearby space need to be controlled. The cult is not using warships. They are suing modified merchant vessels. Making the id harder.

Comment: And carrier groups already got this covered.   They do look at everything aproaching in 3 dimensional space from these operationial ranges (Air, Sea, and Under water are included in this screen.  The subs deployed are usually specialized for anti-submarine operations... not anti-surface ships.).

Answer (score 4):

If we're talking hard sci-fi, I think we just come back to the usual problem that any attacker can just accelerate any projectile to near light speed and chuck it at whatever they want to destroy, and the target has no practical way of defending themselves. If you want to soften your sci-fi, then it's basically up to you what you want to make up to get around this problem.

This might be a bit of a hippy-ish answer that doesn't mean the spirit of your question, but couldn't there be a negotiated outcome to this problem? Both factions obviously value the stargates greatly, and both factions have the ability to destroy the stargates at any time, so either conflict breaks out and the stargates are all very quickly destroyed, either deliberately or accidentally. Or, both sides sit down and hammer out a compromise - stargates can be used for space travel on weekdays, but must be reserved for religious veneration on weekends - something like that?

Comment: I didn’t think of that. Maybe structure something where the cult can have a couple gates for their worshiping and the rest can be trade routes. As for the gate it cannot be “destroyed” but changing its frequency would make it impossible to go where you were going earlier. In other words change the destination.

Comment: An excellent answer that opens more possibilities than it closes. Not hippy-ish at all, but hard-nosed pragmatism completely in line with the old Vulcan proverb: "*Only Nixon could go to China*"

Answer (score 2):

**The terrorists leave mines.**

/ warp space to shorten journeys by a factor of 10/

So this is not a Stargate.  Factor of 10 means there is transit time and something to be transited - some sort of weird space you are traveling thru.

Your terrorists can enter the gate under pretense of being traders.  Then they drop mines behind them in the weird space.  Persons then trying to use the gate will run afoul of the mines.

Depending on the nature of weird space it might be very difficult to clear the mines.

I like the idea that whatever is left within the weird space might achieve the goal of changing the destination of the gate by disrupting the weird space.